# Entity Framework Core - REST json merge patch (Partial Update)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, entity-framework-core

EF Core supports Json Patch - [RFC6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)

https://github.com/aspnet/JsonPatch

I wanted to add support for Json Merge Patch in my app - [RFC7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396)

I am new to entity framework.

I tried following, it works fine, but wanted to know if the implementation is alright (model validation being handled in a filter, so please ignore that part):

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, [FromBody] TEntity updatedEntity)
{
    TEntity entity = repository.GetById<TEntity>(id);
    if (entity == null)
    {
         return NotFound(new { message = $"{EntityName} does not exist!" });
    }
    repository.Update(entity, updatedEntity);
    await repository.SaveAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

And in the repository:

```
public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity, TEntity updatedEntity) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    updatedEntity.Id = entity.Id;
    PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.GetValue(updatedEntity, null) != null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, propertyInfo.GetValue(updatedEntity, null), null);
        }
    }
    entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: @H.Herzl Partial update of a table, if a property is missing in the request json it is not affected. The code posted works fine, basically I want the approach review of my code from experts

Answer (score 2):

Its a bad pattern to use entity types, which reflect an internal schema (your database) in external interfaces (your api).

but for a partial update you can use dynamic like this:

```
dynamic changedData = new { /* props you wanna change */ };
DataContext.Entry(yourEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(changedData);
```

Comment: can you use this for nested classes?